# applying a QUIT function to mini game in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exit, valueerror

So I just started with python and I received the following task;

I need to create a mini game where the game choses a random number from 0-10.
Now I got most of my code but it seems I keep having issues with implementing a `Quit` option.

So the point is that the player can at any time give `Quit` as an answer and then the game quits.
It seems I can not attribute `Quit` in the right way.

When typing the Quit command (`nee`) I keep getting the following error message;

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aarabsa\PycharmProjects\projecten1\Lotto1.2.py", line 22, in <module>
    guess = int(input('Probeer opnieuw of typ nee om het spel te verlaten: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nee'**
```

Could any of you guys give some advise ?

```
import random        
import sys

print("Hello, wat is uw naam?")

naam = input()

print("Kan je de juiste cijfer raden tussen 0 en 10?")

answer = random.randint(0, 10)

guess = int(input('geef uw gekozen nummer: '))


TotalGuesses = 0

while guess != answer:

   TotalGuesses += 1

   if guess < answer:
    
     print('fout antwoord!')
    
     guess = int(input('Probeer opnieuw of typ nee om het spel te verlaten: '))
    
     if guess in ['nee']:
        
        print('Jammer dat je nu al opgeeft ' + naam + ', tot de volgende keer!')
        
        sys.exit()

   elif guess > answer:
    
        print('fout antwoord!')
    
        guess = int(input('Probeer opnieuw of typ nee om het spel te verlaten: '))
    
        if guess in ['nee']:
        
           print('Jammer dat je nu al opgeeft ' + naam + ', tot de volgende keer!')
    
        sys.exit()

     if guess == answer:
    
         break

if guess == answer:

print('Correct ' + naam + '! Je hebt ' + str(TotalGuesses) + 'foutief geraden voordat je de juiste antwoord kon vinden!')
```

Comment: You are trying to convert the text `"nee"` into an integer - that obviously does not work. You need to check if that's the input *before*  converting it

Answer (score 2):

You should convert to an int only if you've first made sure the user didn't enter that string. For example:

```
guess = None  # So it's defined
guess_string = input('geef uw gekozen nummer: ')
if guess_string.lower() == 'nee':
    ...  # tell the user goodbye, or whatever
    sys.exit()
else:
    guess = int(guess_string)
```

Additionally, you could check that their input is a valid number before converting it and assigning it to `guess`. [Here](https://pynative.com/python-check-user-input-is-number-or-string/) is an explanation of how you can do that.

Since you get user input multiple times in your program, you could wrap all that up in a function and just call that, so you don't have repeats in your code.